DeepLinks Vite Electron Oauth2
I am creating an desktop application using electron as our "frontend" the thing is that we want to connect to github using oauth2, so right now what i am doing is front connect to my backend -> redirecting to github -> entering my information etc -> redirecting to my callback in my backend.
Here my problem what i am doing is that
@users_router.get("/test/deep-link") async def deep_link(): return RedirectResponse("test://auth?access_token=123456", status_code=302)
the thing is that it's effectively proposing me to open a electron app but when im saying yes it doesn't works
here the part of my main.ts that i modified
const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock()

if (!gotTheLock) {
  app.quit()
} else {
  app.on('second-instance', () => {
    if (win) {
      if (win.isMinimized()) win.restore()
      win.focus()
    }
  })
}

app.on('open-url', (event, url) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  dialog.showErrorBox('Welcome Back', `You arrived from: ${url}`);
  // const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(new URL(url).search);
  // const accessToken = urlParams.get('access_token');
  // if (accessToken) {
  //   // Store or use the access token as needed
  //   console.log("Access token received:", accessToken);
  // }
});

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('test');
  createWindow();
});


i have some idea the fact that i am working on my D:/ Disk may be a reason, i am on Windows.
Thanks

Try the solution from this SO answer
